# Updating JavaFX ProgressBar works unexpectedly, how?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm in the process of teaching myself JavaFX and I recently stumbled upon "Platform.runLater", which should help you update the UI from inside a time consuming thread.

If I try to set any node inside the task thread, it won't let me because it's not running on the Application thread. HOWEVER, setting the progress of a progressbar works fine. Why is this? I've compared examples of use of the "runLater", and it does what it says until it comes to a "ProgressBar" (i.e, can't set labels or other nodes).

This works, as expected:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(0);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(progressBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+0.1);
                    });
                }

            }

        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

And this too, for unknown reason:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(0);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(progressBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+0.1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Why is this? I've compared both documentation and numerous examples...

Comment: Nearly all JavaFX methods and constructors need to be called from the JavaFX application thread, but not every method and constructor does a check for it.  Some will just fail or misbehave in unexpected or unpredictable ways.  Just because it worked for you *this time* doesn’t mean it will always work.  Using Platform.runLater guarantees it will always work.

Comment: Just because it doesn't throw an exception doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @VGR I hadn't imagined that was possible, but it makes sense. Maybe I've been too trusting of the compiler until this point. How did you figure this out? Did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: The linked duplicate contains references to documentation.  I admit it probably isn’t stressed in the official documentation as much as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

In javafx can only manipulate UI elements such as the `progressBar` from within the dedicated **platform thread**. In your first example you do exactly this:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
  progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+0.1);
});
```

which will execute `progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+0.1);´ within the dedicated UI thread as soon it has free capacity (previous commands have been exectued on it).

In your second example you try manipulate it from your newly spawned thread which will lead to the  `Not on FX application thread ...` exception.

Whenever you want to make changes on the UI elements within some new thread make sure you perform those within

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I thought as well, but as I stated in my question: the second example works just as good as the first! I don't understand this.

Comment: Ah ok, I missread your question then. Does it also properly update the progress bar? Is there a stacktrace printed in your console?